# How to implement Weibo authorize and share in android?

Tags: android, authentication, key, share, social-networking

I tried this code:
http://code.google.com/p/weibo-android-sdk/source/browse/example/src/com/weibo/android/example/AuthorizeActivity.java?r=12
You can get the whole application from http://code.google.com/p/android-weibo-sdk/downloads/list
The authorization worked, but then I changed the appkey and appsecret from the code, with the ones that Weibo gave me with my developers account, having the following code after i changed:

```
private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "1415745064";// Replace a developer's appkey, for example, "1646212960";

private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "8cf118d44c9881b9d1cbf2c4eb957c57";// Replace a developer's appkey, e.g. "94098772160b6f8ffc1315374d8861f9";

private String username = "";

private String password = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mToken = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tvToken);
    mLogin = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    mLogin.setText("oauth!");
    mLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == mLogin) {
                Weibo weibo = Weibo.getInstance();
                Log.d("onclick", "onclick");
                weibo.setupConsumerConfig(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
                // Oauth2.0
                // Implicit authorization and authentication
                Log.d("onclick", "dupa setupconsumerconfig");
                weibo.setRedirectUrl("http://www.sina.com");
                // Here the callback page content should replace the corresponding application callback page with appkey
                // Application callback page landing Sina microblogging development platform developers
                // Into my application - Application Details - Application Information - Senior - authorization settings - application callback page set up
                // and view
                // Application callback page is not empty
                Log.d("onclick", "dupa set redirecturl");

                weibo.authorize(AuthorizeActivity.this, new AuthDialogListener());
                Log.d("onclick", "dupa autorize");



            }
        }
    });

}
```

The rest of the code is the same, but instead of showing me the dialog where i can write my email and password to login, i get an dialog with an error. Some writing in chinese, can't understant id, and than it says: (error:redirect_uri)mismatch).